# How to change column name in specific page template?

Tags: templates, attributes, dynamic-data, asp.net-4.0

I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 with Dynamic Data.
Let's say I have an entity "Student" and it has a required column "DateOfBirth".

I can simply put RequiredAttribute to DateOfBirth metadata field, but I want to do better than that.

At the top of the page, i have "* - Indicates required field."
At the field names, I want that column name to be "* Date of Birth".

But I only want the extra "*" to show up in Edit, Insert and Details page template. I don't want it to show in List template.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out soon after posting this.
I just need to modify Label_Init in EntityTemplates/Default_Edit.ascx.cs and Default_Insert.ascx.cs.

```
    protected void Label_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label label = (Label)sender;
        if (this.currentColumn.IsRequired)
        {
            label.Text = "*";
        }
        label.Text += currentColumn.DisplayName;
    }
```